# Jquery and IE10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have three input fields, input1, input2 and input3.

When the value of input1 changes, input2 is set accordingly:

```
$('input[name=input1]').change(function () {
        console.debug("input1");
    $('input[name=input2]').val($(this).val());
    $('input[name=input3]').prop("disabled", true);
});


$('input[name=input2]').change(function () {
    console.debug("input2");

    ...
});
```

It works, but not on IE10. It doens't print on the console "input1" and "input2" and it doesn't change the input2 value.

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be also in IE<10

It seems to work if I use `on` with `keyup`.

But what if the user uses the mouse to select a cached value?

`mouseenter` has a strange effect.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use 'console.log' instead of 'console.debug' and check if that was a problem for IE to figure!

Comment: I think you got it. `Object doesn't support property or method 'debug'`

Comment: @Aditya: it's the same with console.log or without both console.log and console.debug

Comment: Maybe you could give particular id to each of the inputs and get the value from those inputs using .val() and replace 'this' with the element 'id' just to keep it simple for IE?

Comment: @Aditya: I've already tried by using $('input[name=input2]').val($(input[name=input1]).val()); but nothing happened

Comment: Try $('#input2').val($('#input1').val()); 
where input1 and input2 are the ids ..

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest jQuery you could try to bind an event listener like so

```
$(document).on('change','#input1',changeFunction)
```

older version you might use

```
$('#input1').on('change',changeFunction)
```

and then use the changeFunction(event) to do whatever

Comment: it seems to work if I use `on` with `keyup`. But what if the user uses the mouse t select a cached value? `mouse enter` has a strange effect